# File upload using jquery/ajax for REST API

Tags: ajax, jquery-file-upload

I was trying to upload file to a remote server using REST api by ajax/jquery with the following script, but it returns 400 error with a Bad request. I have tested the end point with curl, which is giving correct response and file is being uploaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {

        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();

        fire_ajax_submit();

    });

});

        function fire_ajax_submit() {

        // Get form
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
        alert(form.files[0]);

        var data = new FormData(form);
        data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");

        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "http://10.13.20.166:5332/fileUploadtoFolder",
            data: data,

            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#result").text(data);
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            },
            error: function (e) {

                $("#result").text(e.responseText);
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            }
        });

        }
```

Comment: var fd = new FormData($("#fileinfo")); change this to var fd = new FormData($("#fileinfo")[0]);

Comment: Thanks Prabhjot for your reply. But I'm sorry that I placed the wrong code initially, as I was trying different codes for uploading. But this code looks perfect to me but it didn't work and getting 400 error.

Comment: You are probably missing headers in the request. 400 error is for missing headers.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to add that? I'm not that experienced in this technology.

Comment: Can you post code of your html form?

Comment: <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <input type="text" name="extraField"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="files"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

Comment: Kindly post code of http://10.13.20.166:5332/fileUploadtoFolder in the question itself not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
var data = new FormData(form);
```

Use this code

```
// Create an FormData object
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileUploadForm"));
```

Try again